# Is this a known or valid divergence between two densities?

Tags: monte-carlo, distance-functions, density-estimation, divergence

I am testing various metrics for learning a density estimate. Specifically, I have a sample of data from a distribution $p$, and am learning a function $f$ to estimate $p$ by minimizing a distance or divergence between the two (via Monte Carlo integration over the sample $p$). The usual metrics such as Cramer-von Mises, Kolmogorov-Smirnov, Mean Integrated Squared Error, etc. are working well as expected. One metric I tried that is yielding surprisingly good results is:

$$d(f, p) = 1 - \int_{\mathcal X} f^\gamma(x) p(x) \, dx$$

where $\mathcal{X}$ is the support of the densities and $\gamma$ is a small value, i.e. close to zero. Note that $p$ is not being raised to the power of $\gamma$ as $p$ is known only through the sample. Is this a valid or known divergence?

Edit: Uploaded an animation of a neural network learning a target density (mixture of 3 Gaussians) via this metric when $\gamma = 10^{-5}$.[image]

Edit 2: I believe this may be working because it is (potentially) approximating a more general class of statistical divergences given by

$$d(f, p) = 1 - \int_{\mathcal X} f^\gamma(x) p^{1-\gamma}(x) \, dx$$

where $0 < \gamma < 1$. It may be working because when $\gamma$ is close to zero, $p^{1-\gamma} \approx p$. Under this more general formulation, the squared Hellinger distance ($H^2$) is a special case when $\gamma=\frac{1}{2}$:

$$H^2(f, p) = 1 - \int_{\mathcal X} f^\frac{1}{2}(x) p^{1-\frac{1}{2}}(x) \, dx$$.

I'm unsure of what the effects are of varying the value of $\gamma$ when using this divergence measure for density estimation. But, going back to my original question, is this (either the general formulation or the specific case when $\gamma$ is close to zero) a known or valid divergence?

Answer (score 1):

The metric you are using is closely related to the (strictly proper) **pseudo-spherical scoring rule**, which probably explains the 'good results' you are seeing.

For an observation $y$, a predictive density $f$ and $\gamma > 0$ the pseudo-spherical scoring rule is defined as
$$
S_\gamma(f, y) = - \left( \frac{f(y)}{\Vert f \Vert_{\gamma + 1}} \right)^\gamma
$$
where
$$
\Vert f \Vert_{\gamma + 1} := \left( \int f(y)^{\gamma + 1} \mathrm{d} y \right)^{\frac{1}{\gamma + 1}} .
$$
It is strictly proper, i.e. its expected score is minimized by the true data generating density. The corresponding divergence function is given by
\begin{align*}
d(f, p) &=  \int \frac{p(y)^\gamma}{\Vert p \Vert_{\gamma + 1}^\gamma}  p(y) \mathrm{d} y - \int \frac{f(y)^\gamma}{\Vert f \Vert_{\gamma + 1}^\gamma} p(y) \mathrm{d} y  \\
&=  \Vert p \Vert_{\gamma + 1} - \int \frac{f(y)^\gamma}{\Vert f \Vert_{\gamma + 1}^\gamma} p(y) \mathrm{d} y .
\end{align*}

It can be shown that for $\gamma \rightarrow 0$ the pseudo-sperical scoring rule converges to the logarithmic scoring rule $S(f,y) = - \log (f(y))$, when suitably scaled. Hence, your approach of estimating the distribution probably works because it is very close to a minimization of the Kullback-Leibler divergence (the divergence of the logarithmic scoring rule).

#### References

- Gneiting and Raftery, [Strictly Proper Scoring Rules, Prediction, and Estimation](https://doi.org/10.1198/016214506000001437)
- Yu et al., [Pseudo-Spherical Contrastive Divergence](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2021/file/bc5fcb0018cecacba559dc512740091b-Paper.pdf)